# CSS Div covering other divs behind it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing today about an issue I am experiencing about a notifciation system I have coded. In the background of the image below is a flash file game file which I have embedded, I have coded a web socket server that sends notifications from the sames C# server to the javascript client code and sends a notification.

preview image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQqxo.png

As you can see from above, I have highlighed one of my notifications, the issue is that sometimes some of the elements on the flash file, and from what you can see the close button on one of my notifications is not clickable due to one of the div's covering the close button except a small bit on the right side of the button is clickable.

I'll run you through my setup..

Javascript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181/');

var hasConnected = false;

function startWebSockets() {
    ws.onmessage = function (messageEvent) {
        onReceiveMessage(messageEvent.data);
    };

    ws.onopen = function () {
        onConnectionOpened();
    };

    ws.onclose = function () {
        onConnectionClosed();
    }
}

function onReceiveMessage(messageData) {
    var messageParts = messageData.includes('\\') ? messageData.split('\\') : messageData;

    if (messageData.includes("\\")) {
        if (messageParts[0] == "compose:show_custom_notification") {
            showBootstrapNotification(messageParts[1], messageParts[2], messageParts[3], messageParts[4]);   
        }
    }   
    else {
        if (messageData == "compose:authentication_complete") {
            console.log('Authentication to WebSocket server has been completed.');
        }

        if (messageData == "compose:authentication_failed") {
            sendMessage("client_identity_token " + habboSso);
        }
    }
}

function onConnectionOpened() {
    console.log('Connected to the WebSocket server.');
    hasConnected = true;

    sendMessage("client_identity_token " + habboSso);
}

function onConnectionClosed() {
    if (!hasConnected) {
        console.log('Failed to connect to the WebSocket server.');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Your connection to the WebSocket server was unexpectedly closed.');
    }
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    if (hasConnected) {
        ws.send(message);
    }
}

startWebSockets();

function showBootstrapNotification(notificationTitle, notificationContent, notificationColor, notificationSize) {
    console.log('trying to execute notification');

    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    var notificationHtml = '';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="col-md-' + notificationSize + ' absolute-center">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="draggable panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: ' + notificationColor + '">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    const newNot = $(notificationHtml);
    notificationArea.prepend(newNot);
    newNot.draggable();
}
```

This is where I store my notification div's:

```
<div id="notification_area">
    <br><br>
    <!-- Notificiations will automatically be added here. -->
</div>
```

If you read the showBootstrapNotification function it adds inside of that div notification_area

I guess what I am asking is, how can I stop div's from being unclickable? why is it taking up so much space when the notifications are much smaller than what the size its taking up is? Is it something to do with the col-md? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the js but you tried giving the notification panel a higher z-index just to force it on top of everything?

```
.notification-area {
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: But if I have multiple notifications open and they all have a z-index of 100, which one is going to come out on top?

Comment: This also isn't at all useful because it doesn't help me when the flash is unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, col-md-1 takes up 1/12 of the width of the screen, col-md-2 is 2/12, col-md-3 is 3/12 and so on. As for making a certain div always clickable, try adding a high z-index to that div in CSS.

```
.div-to-click{
   z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: But what happens when this is covering the flash file? the flash file is also unclickable.. how can I fix this?